# How to print out variable name instead of value?

Tags: python, debugging

If I have a list of variables and each variable is assigned to an equation,
how can I print the variable itself from the list not the result of the equation

For example:

```
x = 1 + 1
y = 2 + 2
z = 3 + 3

list = [x, y, z]

print(list[0])
print(list[1])
print(list[2])
```

Should print out:

```
x
y
z
```

Instead of:

```
2
4
6
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [print() method to print passed expression literally along with computed output for quick debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57513765/print-method-to-print-passed-expression-literally-along-with-computed-output-f)

Comment: If you want to print the letters as text then you have to put them in your list as text: `'x'`, `'y'`, `'z'`.

Comment: if you want strings to be printed, do `list = ["x", "y", "z"]`, a variable name should NOT be needful information at all, that is ONLY developer-use data

Answer (score 1):

print() giving you a values of list[0], or list[1] or list[2]
You gave them values 2,4,6 at the start of your app

```
x = 1 + 1
y = 2 + 2
z = 3 + 3
```

if you want to get x,y,z try this:

```
x = "x"
y = "y"
z = "z"
```

Comment: But then you loose the values! I don't think the OP wanted to know how to print "x, y, z". They wanted to know how to print variables names whose values are 2, 4, 6

Comment: @chrslg Yes, i didn't get the question at first. but i already added another solution below.

Answer (score 0):

in that case, you will need to change your list to a string, otherwise it will think that it is a variable and print the value assigned to it. to fix this you change line 5 to :     list = ["x","y","z"] -> this way it will print out the string, not the value of the variable x

Answer (score 0):

The answers here are obviously correct, but perhaps they miss the real point. I presume you want to be able to show/use *both* the names and the values, for instance print something like "the sum of x, y, z is 12".

If this is the case you may want to work with Python's builtin namespaces, but the simplest thing is to use a dictionary where your names will be the keys and your values... well, the values:

```
my_dict = {}
my_dict['x'] = 1 + 1
my_dict['y'] = 2 + 2
my_dict['z'] = 3 + 3

','.join(my_dict.keys()) #'x,y,z'
sum(my_dict.values()) # 12
```

Comment: yes that was my point, I want to show both values but dont want them to be strings e.g: https://ibb.co/RBLBb6b

 so here I want the first (i) to be x and the second to be the equation value

Answer (score 0):

From your first question i didn't understand well what do you need

I think this can work:

```
def dna_content(seq):
    A = ["A", (seq.count("A") / len(seq)) * 100]

    T = ["T", (seq.count("T") / len(seq)) * 100]
    G = ["G", (seq.count("G") / len(seq)) * 100]
    C = ["C", (seq.count("C") / len(seq)) * 100]
    bases = [A, T, G, C]
    for i in bases:
        print(str(i[0]) + " content is: " + str(i[1]))
```

And... i couldn't find how to acces name of variable through it's value

UPD:

try this:

```
x = 1 + 1
y = 2 + 2
z = 3 + 3
list = ["x", "y", "z"]


for i in list:
    print(i, globals()[i])
```

Comment: This will print a name of variable and its' value by name